# How to destroy a specific user's session data from an admin panel

Tags: php, session, admin

I am creating a login system, without the use of any frameworks.

The admin can access a page where all the users are listed in a table form. 
I have a button in a column for every user named "Sign out user".
If I/The admin press the button,the system/web server should destroy the session of the user I/The admin targeted. 
When the targeted user refreshes his page, I wouldn't be logged in anymore.

Notes:
I am already storing the session_id in the database for the current user.

Comment: You would need a database. And each time a page is loaded you would have a PHP code that would check if the user is in 'active' session. (It's NOT efficient, but it will work.) However, we would definitely love to see a code you have tried.

Comment: I just check if the Session is currently active with a variable in the Session, 'active' if you may. And every time a page loads and the user is in the session, I just update the database with the user_id currently also in one of the Session variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily hijack that session and then destroy it since you have the session id. Simply get the session id from the server and pass it this function.

```
function destroy_third_party_session($in_session_id){
  session_id($in_session_id); // Sets the session id;
  session_start(); // starts the session as that session id
  session_destroy(); // destroy the session
  session_commit();
}
```

Comment: I will try that. When I give the session ID to the session_ID(), will I be "using" the targeted user's session? And then force log him out?

Comment: I found in the phpdocs, a unlink('session.save_path').'\sess_'.$in_session_id);  But I get a Resource temporarily unavailable warning when trying to delete the user's session file on the web server

Comment: Yes, you will be using the users session but since you are immediately destroying the session, it should not matter. I am not sure about what is suggested in the phpdocs.