# Delete session for remote user - Logout remotely in PHP - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I am using database to save user sessions in codeigniter.

```
$sess_array = array('id' => $new_cus_id,
                    'cus_email' => $email);
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
```

Config:

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path']       = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

In the database table, there is an `id, ip_address, timestamp, data (blob)`.
How can I find a specific user's session data and delete it to invalidate the online session.

Comment: @B001ᛦ : Session id is a random character string. How to retrieve user id from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to destroy a specific user's session data from an admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742747/how-to-destroy-a-specific-users-session-data-from-an-admin-panel)

Answer (score 1):

A dirty trick that may help you.

You may find the sessions belonging to a specific email by doing something like this on the sessions table

```
select id, ip_address, cast(data as char(1000)) datablob
from internal.ci_sessions
having datablob like '%email@domain.com%';
```

You may encounter multiple entries belonging to previous sessions along the the currently active one.

once you've found them, just delete those rows and the session will be effectively terminated and the user will be forced to re log-in

Be advised: this is not something you should do often. Messing with the sessions table may cause undesired effects if you happen to touch something you shouldn't. Also, if your session table has gotten big after many months/years of use with no periodic housekeeping, deleting one or more rows can cause a temporary performance impact if the table needs re-indexing. Don't say I didn't warn you :)

If this is not something you need to do for an emergency and can take the time to code it, my suggestion is what I usually do (yes, biased suggestion, I know :) )

> 1.- add a "force logout" field to the table with your user information.

Default this field to "N" or something similar. 
On every page view (I do it on the controller's construct), query the user's table for the flag. If "N" is returned, skip to whatever the user is going.

> 2.- log-out the user if there's a logout flag

If the flag returns as "Y", destroy the user's session and redirect the user to your log-in page. After doing that (you could also do it upon a successful log-in) remember to reset the flag to N in order to prevent the user entering a logout loop.

This adds one query to each pageview, but the impact should be negligible

Comment: This is working. But, you are right it's a messy solution. What's the right way to implement this? I am sure there should be a better way around.

Comment: Definitely, there are better ways. Think of this solution simply as a quick and dirty way to forcibly log-out someone in case of emergency. The really right way would be to flag the user (in your users table, for example) as logged out and in the the next pageview, if you see the user is flagged, use CI to invalidate the session and redirect the user to your log-in page. This will require some (not much) coding and possibly some modifications to your users table, but it's definitely a cleaner solution

Comment: what if the user is deleted? you can't flag it. so you have no other choice but to use your solution above OR extend the session driver with an extra column user_id that is updated at every request.

Comment: Yes, in that case you would not be able to flag the user. We could go into an opinionated debate about the benefits of soft-deleting (deactivating) versus hard-deleting but it would be pointless. In you delete users, I'd suggest "killing" their sessions upon user deletion, effectively logging them out and locking them out (so no need to force logout them later)

Answer (score -2):

simply you can set custom sesstion data with `$this->session->set_userdata('my_custom_session_data',true)` and every where you want to check it use `if($this->session->userdata('my_custom_session_data') == true)`. or to delete it `$this->session->unset_userdata('my_custom_session_data')` or `$this->session->userdata('my_custom_session_data','')`